# export search_api settings with features

Tags: features, search

I used features to export search_api settings and in the feature_module.features.inc file was code that started like below:

I am trying to do the same thing again and I can't find the option to export these settings in features any more. Any idea how to do it?

```
>   /**  * Implements hook_default_search_api_index().  */ function
> vimn_search_default_search_api_index() {   $items = array();  
> $items['node_search'] = entity_import('search_api_index', '{
>     "name" : "Node search",
>     "machine_name" : "node_search",
>     "description" : null,
>     "server" : "solr",
>     "item_type" : "node",
>     "options" : {
>       "index_directly" : 0,
>       "cron_limit" : "50",
>       "fields" : {
>         "nid" : { "type" : "integer" },
>         "title" : { "type" : "text" },
>         "created" : { "type" : "date" },
>         "changed" : { "type" : "date" },
```

Comment: Have you found the way to export this in features? I am also looking how to do this

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem today too.  Features would not display my search_api index for export.  It also wasn't displaying my Page Manager pages, Page Manager handlers, or Views.

I realized the problem was that I had moved all of those configurations into a custom module.  Features wouldn't try to export anything that is module-provided, even if those items had been created through that site's UI in the first place.

I disabled the module (without un-installing) and Features was happy to let me export my index configuration after that.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I found that you can not export index setting, if your solr server does not turn on.